# Should I use SQL limit or not for performance reason?

Tags: php, performance, caching, limit, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2 for a project, it'll have a high traffic, and I'm concerned about performance.

Sometimes I'll have to load a lot entities for "pagination" purposes.

Example: loading 30,000 published articles and I'll need to paginate these results.

I'm wondering how bad is it to load so much rows from databases where I could use LIMIT OFFSET sql statements, however using Doctrine 2 & Pagination, It'll be much more overhead to implement a Paginator adapter (complex repositories, etc.) where I could use a simple Iterator Adapter.

I guess with a good caching system, it shouldn't be a problem, but I'm not really sure.

By the way, do you have any tips about the cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is, with whatever pagination solution you go with, does it actually load 30,000 records when you're only displaying 10 on a page, or does it only load the 10 needed?

If it does load all the records just to display the 10, then it's insane, and you'll have performance problems. Any pagination solution that's actually worth using will load only the records necessary.

Also, cache isn't intended to solve these kinds of problems (i.e to hide an inefficient algorithm). Write efficient code, that is fast, and cache will make your responses even faster.

Finally, in a typical application, the space allotted for fast cache is very precious, so don't fill it up with a bunch of stuff you don't need. Keep it tight so your cache can help make as much of your app as speedy as possible.

Comment: +1 since you should always try to get only the information you need from the database. If you display 10 records, you should fetch 10 records and use a count() to determine the grand total. Or fetch 11 records where you only show a next button if the 11th record is present. Then you don't need to count.

Answer (score 2):

I've not used Doctrine before, but almost all the approaches I've seen to pagination *definitely* do not load the full table of data to do pagination. In the most basic way, you do two queries: one to calculate the number of records (`SELECT COUNT(*) ...`) and another to get the actual rows you need (`SELECT * ... LIMIT ...`). MySQL provides a nice simplification of this with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and [`FOUND_ROWS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

However, I worked on a project once where the data views I needed involved some rather complex joins of several tables with tens of millions of records. Performing the `COUNT(*)` was taking upwards of 8 seconds per hit. What I ended up doing for pagination was to take a slightly more realistic approach: People don't *really* use pagination. I mean, you don't go past page one 99% of the time, right? The amount of people who would go past page 10 is minuscule, so I changed my query to select the first `pageSize * 10 + 1` records (201, in my case). If the number of records found was 201, then I simply printed `"You are on page 1 of 'lots'"`.

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine 2 makes this a little more painful than it would otherwise be.  This is a price you pay for the ORM abstraction.

Loading tens-of-thousands of rows from the database is *bad*.  Hydrating them all (turning them into entities) is **hideously bad**.

Luckily, there's some help in the [DoctrineExtensions package](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions).  The Paginator extension helps grab just the slice of records you need, and hydrates only those entities.  It does so in three queries (in the general case), which is about the best you can hope for:

1. Counts the total number of matching records
2. Fetches the `id`s for the current page's entities
3. Fetches just those entities.

I've used the extension with good success on a couple of occasions, and it's performed well for me, for sets of thousands of records.  It's not clear (to me) how well it will scale to larger datasets or high-traffic scenarios, but it's at least a start.

Comment: I didn't this adapter however I knew about DoctrineExtensions, however, I use a ServiceLayer which makes use of this adapter difficult for this project, but good to know about it anyway